# Find a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is path connected but is locally connected at none of its points.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I'm doing this exercise:

> Let $X$ denote the rational points of the interval $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ of $\mathbb R^2$. Let $T$ denote the union of all line segments joining the point $p=(0,1)$ to points of $X$.
>
> 1. Show that $T$ is path connected, but is locally connected only at the point $p$.
> 2. Find a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ that is path connected but is locally connected at none of its points.

I've no problems with part a. But I'm getting stuck with part b. Any hints/ideas how I can construct such a subset ?

Comment: For 2., have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve ! This might give you a satisfying example.

Comment: @jibounet Topologist's sine curve is locally connected at some points.

Comment: You're right, sorry ! Do not take my comment into account.

Comment: I suspect the idea is to make use of $T$.  What happens to local connectedness at $p$ if we stack a unit vertical translation of $T$ on top of $T$?  "It's Turtles all the way up."

Comment: @hardmath you will need to have infinite copies of $T$, stacked on top of each other

Comment: I **really** like William Elliot's answer to this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2267036/path-connected-space-that-is-not-locally-connected).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $T$ be a previous space, and define $S$ as follows: Let $Y$ denote the set of rational points of the interval $[0,1]\times \{1\}$. Let $S$ denote the union of all line segments between the point in $Y$ and the point $q=(1,0)$. Consider $S\cup T$.

Comment: Is my edit correct ?

Comment: @Kasper Yes, you are correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Part b) can be done using similar ideas as part a). 
define $T = \{[(q,0),(0,1)]|q\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ $\bigcup$ $\{[(q,1),(1,0)]|q\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ where $[x,y]$ denotes the line joining $x$ and $y$. Then $T$ is path-connected as it is the union of path-connected line segment $p = [(0,1),(1,0)]$ and the union of other line segments all of which intersects $p$. But it is not locally connected at any of its point due to similar reason as in part a).